# Php Unset All Keys

Tags: php, arrays, unset

My question might seems basic but still, can't figure how to works this out.

Consider an array of my favorite fruits

```
$array = array("Banana","Rasberry","Blackberry")
```

I'm looking to clear this array so that all keys and values would be erased. My array would be empty just like if I had wrote

```
$array = array();
```

Then, I could `array_push` some new data in.

I thought that I could `array_walk($array, unset($array[$key])` but it's not working properly.

Comment: If i get you you want to `clear this array so that all keys and values would be erased.` What stops you from using `$array = array();` ???

Comment: What's the matter with `= array()`? That's the easiest/quickest way to empty out an array. By analogy, would you empty out a string by looping over each character and erasing it? No, you just do `$str = ''` and get on with life.

Comment: What's wrong with just blowing it away?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question includes the best solution for your situation:

```
 $array = array();
```

This is the fastest way to make the `$array` variable point to an empty array.

Comment: True that. I was too focus on a function to do it.